# How Can i solve this exception of http?

Tags: https, spray

spray.http.IllegalUriException: The path of an URI without authority must not begin with "//"

Comment: Depends on what you are doing. You are probably passing an invalid string I to an Uri constructor. E.g. Only part of a Uri or a Uri missing `http://`

Comment: I am passing this uri https://5af1b521-afd0-43f8-8649-eb56da254b00-bluemix:ccc81b038ddb3f18882b3b19203069334694a5d62c62b757b3f3533f8169f003@5af1b521-afd0-43f8-8649-eb56da254b00-bluemix.cloudant.com What is the error in this URI?

Comment: Works for me: ```scala> Uri("https://5af1b521-afd0-43f8-8649-eb56da254b00-bluemix:ccc81b038ddb3f18882b3b19203069334694a5d62c62b757b3f3533f8169f003@5af1b521-afd0-43f8-8649-eb56da254b00-bluemix.cloudant.com/")
res0: spray.http.Uri = https://5af1b521-afd0-43f8-8649-eb56da254b00-bluemix:ccc81b038ddb3f18882b3b19203069334694a5d62c62b757b3f3533f8169f003@5af1b521-afd0-43f8-8649-eb56da254b00-bluemix.cloudant.com/
```

Comment: but why its not working in IBM Bluemix using python notebook

Comment: How is this related to spray? You will have to provide some code to prevent that everyone will only have to guess :)